# Desktop icons with check boxes

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons, touchscreen

The icons on the desktop are displayed by default with a check box. Clicking on one of them will check the box, and a second click is needed to launch the app. Any idea on how to cancel this 'check box' thing? It is also possible to select multiple icons at a time, as seen on the picture.

As this is the first time ever I see such a behaviour, and this is my first computer with a touch screen, I think these 2 elements could be related to each other ....

[image: desktop icons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, touch enabled devices display this by default.

Type the word `folder` into your Start menu, then click `Folder Options` from the search results that display in the menu.  From the `View` tab of the window that pops up, find the option to disable "use checkboxes to select items".

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/7dad6051-df43-4765-8aa8-d56e625091d0/check-mark-boxes-next-to-desktop-icons